# vb.net and crystal report print label if exist

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I am using vb.net and crystal report for printing. What i want to do is if the item exists with the database then label and value were display in crystal report printing. It is possible? can anyone give an idea on how to do this.

thanks in advance

tirso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a section in you report for these fields and write formula in supress to show or hid this section

```
ISNULL({tablename.fieldname})
```

Comment: Hi jack, It would help me a lot to use a section to work it out. Thanks